# C++ Undeclared Class Error

Tags: c++, class

I am new to C++ and trying to learn classes, but got messed up with a little code. I have made a LIBRARYITEM class and its giving error. I am using two public functions `INPUT()` which takes input and `PURCHASE()` which asks user how many copies of book he wishes to purchase.  Here is the code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LIBRARYITEM LIBRARYITEM;
    LIBRARYITEM.INPUT();
    LIBRARYITEM.PURCHASE();
}

class LIBRARYITEM
{
public:
    void INPUT();
    void PURCHASE();
private:
    int ITEM_NO;
    char ITEMTITLE;
    float PRICE;
    int TOTALCOAST(int N);
};

void LIBRARYITEM::INPUT() {
    cout << "PLease input item no. - ";
    cin >> ITEM_NO;
    cout << "Please input title- ";
    cin >> ITEMTITLE;
    // We will assume price that per copy is 100$
    PRICE = 100;
}
void LIBRARYITEM::PURCHASE() {
    cout << "How many copies you wish to buy - ";
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Total cost for books is - ";
    cout << TOTALCOAST(N);
}

int LIBRARYITEM::TOTALCOAST(int N) {
    return N * PRICE;
}
```

And the error log is -

```
Error   1   error C2065: 'LIBRARYITEM' : undeclared identifier  z:\csci 125\projects\project1\project1\source.cpp   8   1   Project1
Error   2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'LIBRARYITEM' z:\csci 125\projects\project1\project1\source.cpp   8   1   Project1
Error   3   error C2065: 'LIBRARYITEM' : undeclared identifier  z:\csci 125\projects\project1\project1\source.cpp   9   1   Project1
Error   4   error C2228: left of '.INPUT' must have class/struct/union  z:\csci 125\projects\project1\project1\source.cpp   9   1   Project1
Error   5   error C2065: 'LIBRARYITEM' : undeclared identifier  z:\csci 125\projects\project1\project1\source.cpp   10  1   Project1
Error   6   error C2228: left of '.PURCHASE' must have class/struct/union   z:\csci 125\projects\project1\project1\source.cpp   10  1   Project1
```

Comment: I think your problem is here: `LIBRARYITEM LIBRARYITEM;` `LIBRARYITEM` should be called something else, see laser_wizard's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your class declaration above `main()`.
In `main()`, declare an instance of your class, try not to name that instance (or variable) the same name as the class itself.

```
int main()
{
    LIBRARYITEM item;
    item.INPUT();
    item.PURCHASE();
}
```

Comment: Having the same name for a class and an instance of that class is syntactically legal, but as you note, it's probably a bad idea in  practice.  Also, it's common practice in C and C++ to reserve upper case identifiers for macro definitions.  But the real problem in OP's code is that the class must be declared before attempting to create an instance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why C++ compiles so stupidly, just putting the main() at end of program works like charm -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


class LIBRARYITEM
{
public:
    void INPUT();
    void PURCHASE();
private:
    int ITEM_NO;
    char ITEMTITLE;
    float PRICE;
    int TOTALCOST(int N);
};

void LIBRARYITEM::INPUT() {
    cout << "PLease input item no. - ";
    cin >> ITEM_NO;
    cout << "Please input title- ";
    cin >> ITEMTITLE;
    // We will assume price that per copy is 100$
    PRICE = 100;
}
void LIBRARYITEM::PURCHASE() {
    cout << "How many copies you wish to buy - ";
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Total cost for books is  $ ";
    cout << TOTALCOST(a);
}

int LIBRARYITEM::TOTALCOST(int N) {
    return N * PRICE;
}

int main()
{
    LIBRARYITEM LIBRARYITEM;
    LIBRARYITEM.INPUT();
    LIBRARYITEM.PURCHASE();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```